# How to buy on "owned by me" elastic ip address in aws?

Tags: amazon-web-services, ip

I want to buy an own ip address which i can use for my aws server as elastic ip. How is this possible?

Comment: Short answer: you can't.  You'll have to find a hosting service in Morocco if you want to use an address in that country.

Comment: Sorry, voted to close as off topic. Also, I covered that you can't do this and the alternative solution in my post on your related question. The closest you can come would be a VPN client on your rc2 instance - which is not great design.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do exactly what you're saying, but you can do similar.

In AWS you can "[bring your own IP address](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-byoip.html)". You can't buy it through AWS, but if you can purchase an internet /24 CIDR block externally you can add it to your AWS account and use the IP. Once it's in your account you can use it as an elastic IP address.

I suspect this is going to cost more than you would like. Last I heard informally this might cost you $5K to $10K. You're probably going to need to look for another solution to your problem.

Comment: But you can’t buy just one address. The OP would need to buy a /24 in order to advertise it.

Comment: I don't have any knowledge of the IPv4 market, so you could be right. "Bring your own IP address" seems to mainly be for organisations that already have an internet CIDR block, so they can bring (from my read of the docs) a /24 or wider into AWS.

Comment: @Tim good answer, that was exactly I was looking for. So routes to my network would automatically be spread by a protocol, right?
What would be the "Geolocation" of this network?

Comment: My understanding of the deep network protocols is light. I expect BGP will advertise the IP block. Geolocation I don't really know, but I guess geolocation will eventually resolve to where the IP is being served from. You might be able to update that, but there are many geolocation providers so I doubt you'll be successful. Remember you need to bring a public /24 network, and they're somewhat expensive and in short supply. This may not actually solve your problem - when you run into a brick wall please ask a question which describes your problem, rather than your proposed solution.